# Sending a email for all classes with python

Tags: python, python-3.x

My goal is to create a class for each page found in a JSON file.
The sending of emails worked untill i tried doing it with classes.
Does anybody know what im missing here?

```
class Page_Class:
    def __init__(self, email_sender, email_receiver, client, subject, text):
        self.email_sender = email_sender
        self.email_receiver = email_receiver
        self.client = client
        self.subject = subject
        self.text = text

        # Call the send_mail function inside the __init__ method
        self.send_mail()

    def send_mail():
        email_password = "test"
        global subject
        global email_sender
        global email_receiver
        global text
        body = "text"

        em = EmailMessage()
        em['From'] = email_sender
        em['To'] = email_receiver
        em['Subject'] = "subject"
        em.set_content(body)
        context = ssl.create_default_context()

        with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465, context=context) as smtp:
            smtp.login(email_sender, email_password)
            smtp.sendmail(email_sender, email_sender, em.as_string())

        Read_Database(databaseId, headers)
```

Comment: _Does anybody know what im missing here_ - yes, you lack basic understanding of how class/OOP works. In the `__init__` you initialize some attributes, but then you don't use them. `send_mail` is missing at least `self` parameter, if it is instance method.

Comment: There's no apparent need to use a class here. What problem are you having? If you *do* have a class, at least keep sending the mail separate from creating the object, i.e., don't call `self.send_mail()` from inside `__init__`.

Comment: `send_mail` is missing `self` as a parameter, and should use the attributes you set in `send_mail`, not global variables, to create the `EmailMessage`.